# Obtain Duration of a quarter in Luxon

Tags: javascript, typescript, luxon

I'm trying to obtain the Duration (or start and end dates) of an arbitrary 'quarter' in Luxon.

For example, suppose I want the beginning and ending dates of the 3rd quarter knowing only the quarter:

```
const quarterInQuestion = 3;

const startDateOfQuarter = DateTime.fromFormat(quarterInQuestion.toString(), 'q');
```

This will give me the start date of the quarter, but how can I obtain the end date as well.  I've looked into Durations and Intervals but can't seem to get anything to work yet.

Many thanks!

Comment: The end date of the quarter should be one day prior to the start date of the next quarter. Can you calculate it based on that?

Comment: I thought about that...and yes.  But I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do it using Luxon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want [the `endOf` method](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeendof), to which you can pass the period that you want the end of from a date.

```
const startDateOfQuarter = DateTime.fromFormat('3', 'q');
const endDateOfQuarter = startDateOfQuarter.endOf('quarter')
```